# Migrating a Qt QGL based project to use OpenGL 4.3

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es

Ever since I first started my current Qt project around 6 months ago, it has been using what I believe is version 1.3 of OpenGL. However as of recently, I've been itching to actually start improving the way I render things, and it appears that I'm missing many functions that appear to be used in later OpenGL versions.

Since Qt apparently supports OpenGL 4.3, I would like to switch over to it for multiple reasons, but I hear that many functions are also no longer supported.

What would be the best course of action for migrating to version 4.3?

For instance, the mesh component of all render-able objects in my engine handles binding the vertices through the `setAttributeArray();`, and then renders them through the use of `glDrawArrays(mode,start,range);`

I'm just worried that I may end up having several hundred errors and substantially change the way many things work, which is why I'm curious if anyone has any advice for making the change over.

My reasons for wanting to do this is because I'm looking to implement more graphical effects like SMAA or FXAA, shadows, or even just mipmaps, and all tutorials I've found for each of those categories utilized functions above OpenGL 1.3

Comment: That sounds more like a more generic "How to port from Legacy OpenGL (OpenGL 1.x) to modern OpenGL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know of the existence of the QOpenGLFunctions and QOpenGLWidget classes, which I both extended into a new class of my own to acquire the newer functions I desired.

I used to extend solely the QGLWidget, but by doing what I just mentioned above, I was able to maintain most of my previous work and mostly change just declarations.